# Asp.Net SimpleMemberShip Role Management?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I managed the roles before with asp.net configuraition tool. I installed Mvc 4. I created a new mvc 4 internet app. It use simpleMembershipProvider and it is not compatible with asp.net configuration tool.

Is there any simple way to manage userRoles? Should I manage them with hardcode? And Could you give more information about simpleMembershipProvider? (usage, adventages, etc...)

Thanks I lot...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this page you need to either administer roles directly in the database or write your own pages to manage roles:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

> The ASP.NET membership system is set up to support roles. However, unlike membership registration > and login, the Starter Site template does not contain pages that help you manage roles. (Managing > roles is an administrative task rather than a user task.)"

Comment: sucks :-( hasn't anybody made something for this?

Answer (score 0):

This page contains a great overview of just about everything you need to know

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Specifically on role management the options are as follows

> WSAT is built to work with ASP.NET Membership, and is not compatible
> with Simple Membership. There are two main options there:
>
> - Use the WebSecurity and OAuthWebSecurity API to manage the users and
>   roles
> - Create a web admin using the above APIs
> - Since SimpleMembership
>   runs on top of your database, you can update your users as you would
>   any other data - via EF or even in direct database edits (in
>   development, of course)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with trying to code this myself and looking for step by step tutorials, I found this package that auto builds a very simple user/role management system. It will need to be extended to your project, but it should give you the start/example to build upon:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleMembershipAdministration/